# Does string theory need operator formalism to quantize?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, second-quantization, quantization

Can we really use path integral approach to quantize for (first-quantized) string theory? This question is motivated from the following fact: even though we can establish exact correspondence between operator formalism and path integral formalism, details of this correspondence differ for different QFTs. String theory is considered general, and if path integral can be used generally, it would mean that there is some universal path integral approach to quantize a theory. This seems like a too beautiful picture to be true, so my guess is that string theory still relies on operator formalism to quantize. Would this be correct?

Comment: Are you asking about the operator formalism? Note that there also exists a Hamiltonian phase space path integral formulation.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes. I edited: hamiltonian to operator operator formalism.

Comment: I think Qmechanic was hinting at a misconception that appears in your question. (Free) QFT doesn’t have any ambiguities in the phase space path integral formalism, as it is fully equivalent to the operator formalism.

Comment: Also are you talking about first or second quantized string theory? The latter is known as string field theory.

Comment: Significantly revised the question.